# React Hook default State of useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am new to React and currently trying to write a Hook for the first time.

I want to add a class called "clicked" to a html element when it is clicked and at the same time I want to add a class called "not-clicked" to all other html elements that has not been clicked.

I tried to achieve it like this:

```
        function MapComponent() {
          const [ClickedRegion, setClickedRegion] = useState("");
        
          function handleClick(event, region) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setClickedRegion(region);
          }
    
    return (
        <svg version="1.1" id="World" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
          <a href="/Australia" title="Australia" className="nav-link">
            <path
              id="Australia"
              className={`svg ${
                ClickedRegion === "Australia" ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"
              }`}
              onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "Australia")}
              d="..."
            />
          </a>
          <a href="/Europe" title="Europe" className="nav-link">
            <path
              id="Europe"
              className={`svg ${
                ClickedRegion === "Europe" ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"
              }`}
              onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "Europe")}
              d="..."
            />
          </a>
             <a href="/Asia" title="Asia" className="nav-link">
            <path
              id="Asia"
              className={`svg ${
                ClickedRegion === "Asia" ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"
              }`}
              onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "Asia")}
              d="..."
            />
          </a>
        </svg>
  );
}
```

The problem is that the "not-clicked" class gets added by default. I only want to add it when the user clicked on a region.

I can't figure out how to achieve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ClickedRegion` has a default value of empty string, you need to return an empty string as the class name.

Create a helper function (outside of the component), and pass it the region of the item ("Australia" for example), and the `ClickedRegion`:

Utility function:

```
const getClickedClass = (region, clickedRegion) => {
  if(clickedRegion === "") return "";
  
  return clickedRegion === region ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"
}
```

Example of usage:

```
className={`svg ${getClickedClass("Australia", ClickedRegion)}`}
```